# Не запускаются файлы с рабочего стола Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, xubuntu, lubuntu

Проблема такова : имеются pdf файлы на рабочем столе, из приложения *"Файлы"* всё спокойно открывается из директории *"Рабочий стол"*, а с самого рабочего стола если запускать `.pdf`

Возникает ошибка:

```
"Не удалось выполнить /path../ Команда не найдена "
```

Ума не приложу, что может быть не так.

Comment: посмотрите права у файла какие

Comment: чтение и запись

Comment: Для уточнения скажу, что pdf копировались из HDD с windows. Попробовал перегрузить их из интернета и опять добавить на рабочий стол - всё работает как надо. Но почему при копировании с жёсткого диска возникают такие проблемы, понять не могу

Comment: @Spakll, возможно группа сбилась

Comment: Попробуйте просто `chmod 777` файлу задать

Comment: @SergeyKovalev пробовал, не помогает

Comment: Тогда попробуйте сменить ему группу

Comment: @SergeyKovalev нет, тоже не помогло. Просто очень странное поведение, с рабочего стола на запускается, а из приложение Файлы работает, хотя файл тот же самый

Answer (score -1):

Шаги для решения этой проблемы просты:

Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши файл, который вы не можете открыть.
Теперь выберите опцию «Свойства» в появившемся меню.
Затем перейдите на вкладку «Разрешения».
Вы увидите, что флажок "Разрешить запускать файл как программу" активен.
Снимите флажок, если это не скрипт, который нужно запускать.
Файл теперь должен открываться правильно.